# For C# in Unity, how could I have a ball that has it's radius shrink by 0.1 units every second?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, size, transform

Just as the title asks. I've tried to figure this out on my own, but since I'm still new, I'm completely stuck on how I could do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some code showing your attempts would be helpful.

Comment: modify its scale with a coroutine

Comment: Shrink/Scale down by  0.1 units, wait for 1 second, repeat again. Do this in a `while` loop with a coroutine function. Which part of this are you having hard time with? A simple Google of "How to scale Object" in Unity should get you started then modify and post what you got in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code you'll need to make the change is something like:

`transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (transform.localScale, targetScale, speed * Time.deltaTime);`

You'll should set your `targetScale` and `speed` earlier in your script. If this were in your update function, I am not sure if it would continuously run 'every second' to the effect that you want. maybe you'll need a coroutine for that part.